# Variable with added content. Hide extra content if variable is empty

Tags: php

I have a variable with other content included at each end, but I do not want the extra content to show if the variable is empty. Can I do this without doing a full if-else. Is there anything I can do with the variable to hide all if variable is empty.

```
<?php if htmlencode($postcode_coveringsRecord['borough']!=""): ?>
<?php echo ' Borough of '.htmlencode($postcode_coveringsRecord['borough'].' area') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some kind of `if`-like condition somewhere, there's no built-in shortcut function in PHP that will do this for you (eg. a function that concatenates a bunch of strings if, and only if, *all* arguments are non-empty).

An alternative method using the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (just an if-else-like construct on one line):

```
echo (empty($postcode_coveringsRecord['borough']) ? '' : ' Borough of '.htmlencode($postcode_coveringsRecord['borough']).' area');
```

(Btw, the closing parenthesis in your example is arguably in the wrong place.)

If you did find this was a common requirement, then you could perhaps write a function:

```
/**
 * Join the passed arguments together.
 * But only if all arguments are not "empty".
 * If any arguments are empty then return an empty string.
 * @param string Strings - Multiple arguments
 * @return string
 */
function joinNonEmptyStr(/* Any number of args */) {
    $result = '';
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $str) {
        // If the argument is empty then abort and return nothing.
        //  - But permit "0" to be a valid string to append
        if (empty($str) && !is_numeric($str)) {
            return '';
        }
        $result .= $str;
    }
    return $result;
}

// Example
echo htmlentities(joinNonEmptyStr(' Borough of ',$postcode_coveringsRecord['borough'],' area'));
```